# 3D Animation Performance Issues in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

In my 3D animation in AnyLogic, if I zoom out, the quality decreases, when I zoom in, it becomes fine. Example shown in these images:

[image]

vs

[image]

Are there settings that can prevent this quality decrease from happening?

Comment: Try playing with the draw distance in the 3D window properties, not sure if that helps

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't help. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply from AnyLogic support as follows:

> Right now, we are working to improve the performance of 2D and 3D
> animation at run-time.  In particular, in the latest version, the
> level of details changes while zooming in 3D window, i.e. objects that
> are further away have less detail than closer objects.  On your
> screenshot, 3D objects look unacceptably bad at a relatively short
> distance and you can do nothing with this. However, as far as I know,
> there will be an option to tune the distance where the quality
> decreases in the next update.